# AES encryption step: calculate the byte substitution process

Tags: aes, finite-field, s-boxes

I am a self learner and tried to learn AES, so I have a book written in my native language. It has some practical examples about finite fields and AES. It has a question that asks me to calculate the byte substitution process in advanced encryption system in GF($2^8$).

The book ask for `10010011`. I know that it is equal to $x^7+x^4+x+1$ in GF($2^8$), but there is not any example about what should be done in substitution layer. When I look at internet, the process proceed via S-box, but I do not know how to go further. I haven't worked with an S-box yet.

Can you help me with this example assignment so I can calculate the rest by myself?

Comment: Dear friend, a nice starting guide is here [A Stick Figure Guide to the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)](https://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html)

Comment: @kelalaka thanks but it didnt help much, I still dont know that result of $x^7+x^4+x+1$ in s box

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box

Comment: https://jedcrandall.github.io/courses/cse539spring2023/miniaesspec.pdf

Comment: @kelalaka is it 0100101110101010 for 10010011 ? can you check me please